# how to parse model in component tag to json by javascript

Tags: json, jsf, components

example:

```
<cc:attribute name="modelDTO" type="com.example.dto.ChartDTO"/>
```

and cc:implement

```
<cc:implement> 
   <script>
     var dto = '${cc.attrs.modelDTO}';
     console.log(dto);
   </script>
</cc:implement>
```

when i'm using this tag, i show log and get `com.example.dto.ChartDTO@520ff6ee`. so, how to parse dto to json in javascript?. i tried `var json = JSON.parse(dto);` but cann't

Comment: You need to take care of that on the server side. There are several libraries to serialize JSON (GSON, Jackson, etc). If you are using OmniFaces, you can use http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/2.6/org/omnifaces/util/Json.html

Comment: .. and there are many others that qualify as duplicate